Magnon blockade
I am new to quantum optics, I see in some papers the term magnon blockade which I do not have any intuition and physical idea about it. I could not find any precise definition of this phenomenon . Some papers like this one uses second-order correlation function to measure the magnon blockade. But for me the physical intuition and mathematical percipience is not clear.

What is a clear definition of magnon blockade (or in some other text photon blockade) ?
How could we formulate this concept in mathematical language?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of magnon blockade in a quantum system (like cavity QED)?

